# send variable to function / global variable

Tags: matlab

I have the variable `delta` in the main and the line: `Y_Q = blkproc(Y_dct, [8 8], @Quantization);`

I need the function `Quantization` to know about the variable `delta`.

Can someone please help me? thanks..

Answer (score 2):

If `Quantization` is a subfunction, it will be able to access variables in the outer function (you can also introduce a subfunction that calls `Quantization` with the callback arguments and any additional values you need).

Another method is to make your shared variable global, using the `global` statement at the top of each function that should share it.